# What is the type of CloseEvent.code in Websockets API

Tags: javascript, websocket, enums

What is the type of [`CloseEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent/code).
Is it an enum?

At the moment I have `errorEvt.code === 1000` but I'd like something like `errorEvt.code === Something.CLOSE_NORMAL` but what is Something?

Comment: Can you add some example how/what you are doing?

Comment: Chances are that `Something` is an enum within the native implementation of the JS engine, and is not exposed outside of the engine itself.

Comment: @Unknown User I have. My problem is that I don't want to write errorEvt.code===1000 because 1000 is not clear to someone reading the code.

Comment: If you want that - you should create your own object with codes like `var Something = {CLOSE_NORMAL: 1000}`. It's standartized codes. The reason is simple, close codes could be custom and protocol implementation doesn't aware of all codes, so it couldn't have enum in it.

Answer (score 1):

These are pre-defined codes in the WebSocket Protocol ([RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)).

> ###7.4.1.  Defined Status Codes

> Endpoints MAY use the following pre-defined status codes when sending
> a Close frame.

> ####1000

> 1000 indicates a normal closure, meaning that the purpose for
>     which the connection was established has been fulfilled.

> ...

This Protocol doesn't define things like "CLOSE_NORMAL", the only references to things like that I can find are on MDN (which you've already linked) and as part of [this Java implementation](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/8.1.17.v20150415/xref/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/WebSocketConnectionRFC6455.html) of the Websocket Protocol.

If you yourself want to reference these codes by their *names*, you can create this object yourself:

```
var Something = {
  CLOSE_NORMAL: 1000,
  ...
}
```

This way you can simply reference the code through this *Something* object via `Something.CLOSE_NORMAL`, etc.